# Submit button reloads page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a problem that I simply can't solve. Here is the code:

```
<form action "time.php" method="POST">
Mjesto polaska:
<select name="pocetak">
<option value='1'>Banja Luka</option>
<option value='2'>Prnjavor</option>
<option value='3'>Prijedor</option>
<option value='4'>Gradiska</option>
<option value='5'>Derventa</option>
<option value='6'>Laktasi</option>
</select>

Odrediste: 
<select name="kraj">
<option value='1'>Banja Luka</option>
<option value='2'>Prnjavor</option>
<option value='3'>Prijedor</option>
<option value='4'>Gradiska</option>
<option value='5'>Derventa</option>
<option value='6'>Laktasi</option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" value="Posalji">
</form>
```

This is written on the page "place.php" but when I click Submit button "Posalji" page reloads itself. Where is the problem? I am using WAMPSERVER.

Comment: `action "time.php"` should be `action="time.php"`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing `=`


Comment: Oh man, I really can't believe I missed "=", I've been stuck on this page for 30minutes because of typo. I'm so embarassed now.

Comment: Don't sweat it; happens to all of us.

Comment: How does that make it off-topic? Half the questions on SO are about forgetting/simple stuff... Valid HTML is on-topic, isn't it? (I'm really asking.)

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your form.  You are missing an equal sign. It should read

```
<form action="time.php" method="POST">
```

With the missing equal sign, there is no action defined, so when the form is submitted, the form just reloads the page on which it is defined.